# FuelPHP: Pick a limited amount of objects from an array of objects (based on properties)

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I need to pick 3 of the latest (10) entries from $data["entries"] and send those to the entries controller of the widgets module. I have no idea how to manage this in the most performant way.

**Here's some code from the controller that calls the module:**

```
$data["entries"] = Model_Entry::find('all', array('limit' => 10, 'order_by' => 'created_at'));
$data["latest"] = Request::forge('widgets/entries/view/', false)->execute($data["entries");
```

**$data["entries"] structure:**

```
[1]=>
   object(Model_Entry)#31 (10) {
      ["_data":protected]=>
      array(9) {
         ["id"]=>
            string(1) "2"
         ["entry_title"]=>
            string(4) "test"
         ["entry_status"]=>
            string(1) "1"
         ["created_at"]=>
            string(1) "0"
         ["updated_at"]=>
            string(1) "0"
      }
   }
[2]=>
   object(Model_Entry)#32 (10) {
   }
...
```

**Entries View:**

```
foreach($entries as $entry): 
   echo $entry->id;
endforeach;
```

Would it also be possible to pick only the objects with a entry_status of 1, of those 10 entries, to avoid another query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you want:

```
$data["entries"] = Model_Entry::query()
    ->where('entry_status', 1)
    ->order_by('created_at')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had a good read in [the docs](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html#find_chaining).